# How to quickly find source of TS functions in VSC without going through node_modules manually?

Tags: visual-studio-code, node.js

I got an issue with digging through 3rd party scripts in VSC. How to quickly find source of TS functions in VSC? Here is part of my puppetter snippet:

```
await session.send('Animation.enable');
  session.on('Animation.animationCreated', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  });
  await session.send('Animation.setPlaybackRate', {
    playbackRate: 2,
  });
```

If I peak the definition of `on()` I get to a `events.d.ts` file where there is only the "header" of the function `on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;` But where is the implementation? How do I find it within the VSC? I wish to see what other string parameters it accepts.

It appears that string "Animation.animationCreated" does not appear in node_modules at all. 
I followed the search to https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol and subsequently to https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/blob/master/types/protocol-proxy-api.d.ts and https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/blob/master/types/protocol-mapping.d.ts and that is where I am stuck now. I don't understand how to find actual implementation of those types. How do they connect exactly with the browser? Should I search the chromium source code next?

Comment: In this specific case probably not at all. Possible events are something you’ll find in the documentation of whatever you’re using.

Comment: The puppeteer page only has this example: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-class-cdpsession so I followed on https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Animation#method-enable and found only a mention of some methods, nothign extensive. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Animation/#event-animationCreated Those string also don't actually appear anywhere in  node_modules so I am guessing this is part of the browser implementation then?